# Magento2: custom header.phtml stays cached forever!

Tags: magento2, custom, cache, header, caching

I have a **child theme**, and uploaded a custom header: `header.phtml`. Right after I uploaded, it showed it correctly in the front-end.

However, changing something in this custom header, never reflects in the front-end. It ALWAYS shows the first version I uploaded. Once I remove the custom file, it falls back to the parent. But if i upload again (a new version): the old version is back!

I tried various ways of cleaning cache:

1. Manually empty folders (**`var/* pub/static/*`**)
2. **`php bin/magento cache:clean`** + **`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`**
3. In the admin itself (**flush static files**, and **all other cache**)

Note: Magento is in developers version, and I am using **v2.1.9**).

I wasted like 6 hours trying everything!

Hope someone can help me out there.

Thanks

Comment: Also, I disabled all cache, so I am surprised it shows the same thing over and over again. Also emptied browser cache! But was not expecting that to help.

Comment: do you have tried try php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Doing it now. Takes a while. But I cannot imagine I have to do this everytime I made changes to a file. Let you know in a bit or it worked.

Comment: @ashish Nope. Didn't work.

Comment: Ah, sure. Basically what I did, I copied the default header.phtml to the child template and then add a string to the hello message for testing purpose: 

$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome() . "TEST";

When loading the front, it shows the TEST nicely, as expected. So I removed the TEST and made my changes. But whatever I change, it always shows the TEST, and none of the changes I made.

Comment: Ok. I switched on the cache, and it showed the new file. But now the new file is ALWAYS showing, not matter what I upload again. Switching cache on/off makes no difference  this time. I am starting to hate Magento! Spent so much time on figuring things out instead of actually doing the website itself. Anyone that knows the solution?

Comment: Ok! I think i figured it out! I restarted PHP, and the file is loading correctly now. So apparently it is PHP / MemCache / opCache or whatever caching the files. Perhaps Magento should include this in their empty cache procedure too (empty/reset memory cache or whatever it is).